# Algorithm for fitting boards to available lengths, minimizing waste

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I'm writing an application to use in the lumber yard. Given a number of board or beam lengths, the goal is to calculate the number of boards needed while minimizing waste. For example, one might have the following shopping list for one particular dimension:

> 3x 2.9 meters
>   5x 1.6 meters
>   21x 0.9 meters

At the lumber yard, one would check the available lengths of boards and enter it into the application. Lets say that this dimension is available in 4.8 meters lengths.

A simple approach would be to try and fit the remaining boards in descending lengths:

> 2.9 + 2.9 = 5.8 so that won't fit on a 4.8 meter board
>   2.9 + 1.6 = 4.5 so that's ok.

No length is less than the remaining 0.3 meters so this board is "full". We will fit two more of this type, and then we have the following lengths left to fit:

> 2x 1.6 meters
>   21x 0.9 meters

Ok, so this algorithm works reasonably well. But what if we instead of fitting the 2.9 + 1.6, we fit 2.9 + 0.9 + 0.9 = 4.7 instead. We will then get 0.1 meters waste per board, instead of 0.3 meters.

One problem in enumerating all possible combinations is that each length might appear more than once in a board, and the number of lengths fitted in a board will vary as well. Is there a known algorithm I can use to minimize the total waste for all boards?

Also, what if there are two or more lengths available at the lumber yard? For instance 5.4, 4.8 and 3.6 meters? This will surely complicate things. One could run the selected algorithm for each available length and pick the length with the least amount of waste. But the most elegant solution would allow mixing the available lengths, so the optimum answer might be something like 1x 5.4, 3x 4.8, 6x 3.6. But for starters, I would be happy with limiting the the answer to one length.

Comment: Sounds like the Cutting Stock problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particular problem is a variant of the so-called "Cutting Stock" class of problems.
Take a look at Wikipedia's "[Cutting Stock Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)" (CSP) page

I like this explanation in plain English of a simpler version of the Cutting Stock Problem.
From [AIMMS](https://www.aimms.com/english/developers/resources/examples/modeling-book-examples/cutting-stock/):

> "Cutting stock problem: how to cut long rolls of material (referred to
> as raws) into smaller rolls of a prescribed size (referred to as
> finals), given a demand for each of the finals."

This [pdf](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_CuttingStock.pdf) by AIMMS is good.

Note that there are quite a number of variations to the Basic Cutting Stock Problem that researchers have come up with. These Integer Programming lecture notes good formulation of the [generalized Cutting Stock problem](http://www.more.ms.unimelb.edu.au/students/integerprogramming/462_sem1_08_notesHSG.pdf) (see page 17)

These MILP problems are not very difficult to formulate because the objective function and the constraints follow the basic pattern of the standard CSP. A huge body of research exists on techniques to solve them efficiently.

If you have access to an LP/IP solver such as CPLEX, R, or the Excel Solver (for smaller problems), it is definitely worth formulating your problem and trying it on these solvers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ram, the bottom two links are not working. Could you update them please?

Comment: @rdtsc Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I've fixed the broken links.

Answer (score 3):

Minimizing the waste is actually optimization problem for generalized [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is [**NP-Complete**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), and thus there is no known polynomial time solution for this problem,

Though NP-Complete, one can produce [pseudo-polynomial solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) for this problem using dynamic programming, or reducing it to [knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (weight=value=length, W=board size), and use its [pseudo-polynomial solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm), which is very similar.

However, in here it is even trickier, the pseudo-polynomial solution assumes integers, while your examples show this is not the case. You can solve it by using [fixed point arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) to represent the lengths (i.e. 4.8 will be displayed as 48, if you are using only one digit after the dot per length, if you are using 2 digits after the dot, it will be 480,...).

Note: this algorithm will minimize the waste for you, but it doesn't guarantee "minimum number of logs" for the minimized waste.

In any case, since finding *any* solution is NP-Hard, finding the solution that uses least logs is also NP-Hard.

Comment: I have some reading to do, to understand your answer fully. But for now, I can at least comment that minimizing the waste is good enough since you pay for the total length bought. It doesn't really matter how many boards there is, if the total waste is the same.

Comment: @Anlo: In this case, the suggested algorithm guarantee it, but beware of exponential behavior, the algorithm might appear polynomial, but it is pseudo-polynomial and misleading, especially since you are using fractional lengths here. However, since the problem is NP-Hard, unless you can use approximation algorithms, you are out of too much choices here..

Comment: Using fixed point arithmetic is no problem at all. Centimeters (480) is probably good enough, millimeters (4800) definately is. Is there some point in trying to keep the numbers small (i.e. use 480 instead of 4800)?

Comment: @Anlo: excellent question! yes! The algorithm's complexity is `(n*W)`, where `n` is the number of logs and `W` is the size of the board. Finding a solution for a board of size 4800 will take 10 times longer (and more space) then a board of size 480.